# Who was the first Gryffindor sorted in Sorcerers Stone?

Tags: harry-potter

In Sorcerer's Stone, who was the first character to get sorted into Gryffindor? Sorting is a very stressful situation in the Harry Potter universe, so who do we have as our first sorted member of Harry Potter's house?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the books, the first person sorted in Harry's year is Hannah Abbott:

> Professor McGonagall now stepped forward holding a long roll of parchment.
>
> "When I call your name, you will put on the hat and sit on the stool to be sorted," she said. "Abbott, Hannah!"
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* Chapter 7: "The Sorting Hat"</sup>

The first Gryffindor, however, is Lavender (emphasis mine):

> "Brocklehurst, Mandy" went to Ravenclaw too, but **"Brown, Lavender" became the first new Gryffindor**, and the table on the far left exploded with cheers; Harry could see Ron’s twin brothers catcalling.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* Chapter 7: "The Sorting Hat"</sup>

In the film, both honours go to Hermione:

> **McGonagall:** Now, when I call your name, you will come forth, I shall place the Sorting Hat on your head, and you will be sorted into your houses. Hermione Granger!
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* (2001)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

**Lavender Brown**

From chapter 7:

> " Brocklehurst, Mandy" went to Ravenclaw too, but "Brown, Lavender"
>   became the first new Gryffindor, and the table on the far left
>   explodedwith cheers; Harry could see Ron's twin brothers catcalling.